# Retrieving Parent and children in JPA without using annotations

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, jpql

this is a question that's been bugging me for days
I have 2 entities, First one is called student

```
@Entity
public class Student {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private int Level;

    @ManyToOne 
    @JoinColumn(name="dep")
    private Department dp;
```

and second one is called department

```
@Entity
public class Department{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
   
    private String name;
```

I also have a repository in which I create my queries:

```
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface StudentRepo extends JpaRepository<Student,Long>{
        @RestResource(path="/myquery")
    @Query("my query here")
    Object [] getLevel();
}
```

My goal is to get each department with the list of the distinct Levels associated with that department, for example

```
[
  [
    "department name",
     [
     level 1,
     level 2,
     level 3,
      ...
     ]
  ]
]
```

I tried using different queries but I couldn't get the levels to be nested inside the department and got this response instead:

```
[
[
"Dep1",
"Level 1"
],
[
"Dep1",
"Level 2"
],
[
"Dep2",
"Level1"
],
...
```

Comment: You can add a default method to your interface that will convert the results to your desired structure using Java. You can't expect every imaginable result structure to be enforceable using Spring Data

Comment: yes I know, but currently my task is to do this with a normal query.

Comment: See the second sentence of my comment

Comment: Yes I think you're right, I've been trying this for hours, I'll probably follow your advice.